# FileNotFoundError: Could not find module when using jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When I try to use jupyter notebook, I got the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-8ec26a89e3fd> in <module>
      4 import matplotlib
      5 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 6 from scipy.io import loadmat
      7 import time
      8 import sys

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py in <module>
    128 
    129     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
--> 130     from . import _distributor_init
    131 
    132     from scipy._lib import _pep440

D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
     57             os.chdir(libs_path)
     58             for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(libs_path, '*dll')):
---> 59                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
     60         finally:
     61             os.chdir(owd)

D:\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, use_last_error, winmode)
    371 
    372         if handle is None:
--> 373             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
    374         else:
    375             self._handle = handle

FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\.libs\libbanded5x.EHDKC2XVYTQQ5MALRS6XN2CUSS6SRL6P.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

But I am sure that the file is right there in the folder. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have the same error when I try to import the last scipy version to python console. I created an issue at github:https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/14002.

Comment: My solution was to downgrade as stated in one of the answers below, however, I do not see why to do so when I saw the DLL on the library, I hope they answer about this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same problem occured when trying to import sklearn.
The version of my scipy is 1.6.3 and i solved the problem by degrading scipy into 1.6.2

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked for me, in order to downgrade you need to do conda install scipy=1.6.2

Comment: Sgdva's suggestion works for me. But in order to downgrade we need to do
`conda install scipy==1.6.2`

Answer (score 3):

It seems to be pretty common when installing scipy. You could try the downgrade, but that did not work for me.

I found that re-installing scipy using:

```
pip install scipy==1.6.3 --user
```

worked to install the missing file.

Answer (score 1):

Same problem while trying to import tensorflow!

FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\anaconda3\envs\test\lib\site-packages\scipy.libs\libbanded5x.EHDKC2XVYTQQ5MALRS6XN2CUSS6SRL6P.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax.

(the file is there)

Answer (score 1):

Reverting scipy (from 1.7.3 back to 1.6.3) or changing scipy version to any other one didn't work for me. What did work, however, is setting up an environmental variable `CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE` to `1` (as suggested [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/14002)). This can be a workaround until the devs fix this.

Answer (score -3):

Delete the spicy folder in the environment "\miniconda\envs\env_name\Lib\site-packages\spicy"
Reinstall using cell magic in the jupyter notebook

```
!pip install spicy
```

Comment: The package is scipy!