# Import error for scipy on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, jupyter-notebook, scipy

I'm having the following error when trying to import scipy:

`FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\[user-name]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\.libs\libbanded5x.2KADQYTNPWKJMTCXD6RBF57D5WTRNEE3.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax`

I was able to import scipy fine a week or so ago, but I had to install top2vec for some analysis, after which this import is no longer working for some reason.

I've tried all solutions I've found on Stack Overflow such as installing a different version of scipy [as stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67377972/filenotfounderror-could-not-find-module-when-using-jupyter-notebook) and setting `CONDA_DLL_SEARCH_MODIFICATION_ENABLE=1` [as mentioned here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/14002), but to no avail.

In case it helps, here are a few more notes:

- I checked and the file mentioned in the error message does exist in the location mentioned, so perhaps it is one of the dependencies that is missing.
- On my Jupyter Notebook, I'm running python 3.8.3 and numpy 1.23.1.

I also created a new environment and activated it by typing "conda activate top2vec". The points below refer to what I get in this environment:

- I'm unable to import scipy on Jupyter but using Powershell, I can import scipy without getting the above error.
- However, when I import top2vec via Powershell, I get the error "`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'top2vec'`" even though conda install top2vec says that "`# All requested packages already installed.`"
- Output of `get-command python`: `CommandType Name Version Source ----------- ---- ------- ------ Application python.exe 3.9.515... C:\Python39\python.exe`
- Output of `get-command conda`: `CommandType Name Version Source ----------- ---- ------- ------ Application conda.bat 0.0.0.0 C:\Users[user-name]\anaconda3\Library\bin...`
- Output of `get-command jupyter`: `CommandType Name Version Source ----------- ---- ------- ------ Application jupyter.exe 0.0.0.0 C:\Users\ [user-name]\anaconda3\Scripts\jup...`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: - what scipy version are you using?
- did you install via pip or conda?
- it's unusual you can import from Powershell (presumably from an interpreter), but not Jupyter. Were the same environments activated?

Comment: It seems likely that Jupyter *or* SciPy was installed through Conda in an environment, but not both. To debug a bit further: how do you start Jupyter? Do you start it from the command line/powershell, or double click some icon, or something else? And in the command line case: what is the command you start it with?

Comment: Also, what are the exact commands you use in PowerShell (and Python prompt) to test those imports? I presume something like `python <newline> import top2vec`? Or perhaps even `python -c "import top2vec"` as a simple one-liner?

Comment: @AndrewNelson I believe I tried installing scipy through both. I installed the latest version but also tried downgrading to 1.6X and 1.7X versions to see if that helped, but it didn't.

Comment: @9769953 I always start jupyter by typing "jupyter notebook" in powershell.  
and yes, I just type "python" in powershell and do "import top2vec".

Comment: I also tried creating a new conda environment and installing packages in that one alone before starting jupyter by typing "jupyter notebook" within that environment and in another attempt through the anaconda navigator, but the import errors inside the jupyter notebook.

Comment: Try starting Jupyter with `python -m jupyter notebook` instead.

Comment: You can figure out what interpreter Pycharm is using from the preferences, then try and use that one as well.

Comment: Sorry, got my issues mixed up

Comment: @9769953 I just tried that. It says "C:\Python39\python.exe: No module named jupyter"

Comment: @9769953 This is strange. I just did "conda install -c conda-forge notebook" and got:
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
# All requested packages already installed.
Retrieving notices: ...working... done

But when I do "python -m jupyter notebook", I get: "No module named jupyter." The same happens with top2vec even though it says it's already installed. Any thoughts as to what is going on? Have been dealing with this for over a week and really need to sort this out to get things done.

Comment: `C:\Python39\python.exe` in the error message doesn't look like that is the Python executable used by Conda, since it would somewhere show Conda in its path. So you have a mismatch between your Python and Conda. Have you activated the Conda environment you intend to be working in?

Comment: @9769953 Yes, I did "conda activate top2vec". I still get "C:\Python39\python.exe: No module named jupyter" even though it says: conda install -c conda-forge notebook
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

# All requested packages already installed.

Comment: @9769953 what do you think is the best way to resolve this? Since I can't figure out anything at this point, do I need to completely delete python and anaconda or is there a better fix (hopefully)? Please let me know if you have any thoughts

Comment: Even though I did "conda activate top2vec", I get this: Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.prefix
'C:\\Python39'
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Python39\\python.exe'

Comment: Before trying a fresh install (which may bump into leftovers from a previous install), first try and see what is where. I don't know PowerShell, but the wisdom of the internet says that `get-command` may help here. Try `get-command python`, `get-command conda` and `get-command jupyter`. It'll be good to know what is located where.

Comment: Once you've located the directory where the `conda` executable lives, also check in that directory if there are Python and Jupyter executables.

Comment: Doesn't this suggest conda and jupyter are in the same directory? What else should I do now?

I just ran jupyter by typing jupyter notebook (note that I already did the conda activate top2vec command), and while import scipy in powershell didn't throw an error, on jupter I still get: FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'C:\Users\[user-name]\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\.libs\libbanded5x.2KADQYTNPWKJMTCXD6RBF57D5WTRNEE3.gfortran-win_amd64.dll' (or one of its dependencies). Try using the full path with constructor syntax. even though this file exists.

Comment: @9769953 I've edited my original post to include the Powershell output of the three get-command commands you suggested.

Comment: I just changed my directory to the C\Users\[user-name]\anaconda3 where conda lives, and got these outputs: Python 3.9.5 (tags/v3.9.5:0a7dcbd, May  3 2021, 17:27:52) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
>>> import top2vec
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'top2vec'

import scipy gives no error, but import top2vec does. But scipy import doesn't work in jupyter.

I really appreciate any insight you may have as I am at a loss

Comment: Any more thoughts on this?